How to upgrade a specific runner in Gitlab?
I've minimal knowledge of Docker-Gitlab. I am trying to do the following:

I've existing runners in the Gitlab.
Need to upgrade one of the runners to the latest version.
I've authenticated from the installed Docker app to Gitlab using the following command:


docker login registry.gitlab.com


Based on the documentation, ran these commands:

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html
hasans@Mds-MacBook-Air ~ % docker stop gitlab-runner

Error response from daemon: No such container: gitlab-runner
hasans@Mds-MacBook-Air ~ % docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
hasans@Mds-MacBook-Air ~ % 

I believe I'm missing something here.
